# TypeORM Share Entities Across Web and Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, typeorm

I am using Webpack 4.7.0 to compile two entypoints - a server (node) and client (React), all in Typescript using ts-loader. I have a set of entity classes I would like them to share, however they are all written to be used by TypeORM (with @Entity decorators), thus requiring an `import x from "typeorm"`.

This, of course, does not play nice when compiling the client bundle, as typeORM depends on many NodeJS libraries. I have tried adding `externals: ["typeorm"]` to my client entrypoint, but I then get a `ReferenceError: "typeorm" not found` in my browser.

Is there any way to share TypeORM entities across platforms?

Comment: If you didn't load it, why should there be `typeorm` global? Of course, it should play nice with client bundle, because the package announces that it supports browsers, https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm